# Flutter - Positional Argument

Tags: flutter, dart, arguments

I am trying to build an e-commerce application and this error message pops up:

> 1 positional argument expected by 'Body.new' but 0 found

This is the contents of splash_screen.dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shop/screens/components/body.dart';
import 'package:shop/size_config.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static var routeName;

  const SplashScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Body(),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the contents of body.dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shop/constants.dart';
import 'package:shop/screens/components/splash_content.dart';
import 'package:shop/screens/sign_in/sign_in_screen.dart';
import 'package:shop/size_config.dart';

class Body extends StatefulWidget {
  const Body(SafeArea Function(BuildContext context) param0, {super.key});

  @override
  State<Body> createState() => _BodyState();
}

class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
  int currentPage = 0;
  List<Map<String, String>> splashData = [
    {
      "text": "Welcome to Amaze, Let's Shop!",
      "image": "assets/images/splash_1.png",
    },
    {
      "text": "We help people to connect with stores\n across India",
      "image": "assets/images/splash_2.png",
    },
    {
      "text": "Just stay home with us",
      "image": "assets/images/splash_3.png",
    },
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const Spacer(
      flex: 2,
    );
    return SafeArea(
      child: SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              flex: 3,
              child: PageView.builder(
                onPageChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    currentPage = value;
                  });
                },
                itemCount: splashData.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => SplashContent(
                  image: splashData[index]['image']!,
                  text: "Welcome to amaze, Lets Shop!",
                  key: UniqueKey(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: List.generate(
                      splashData.length,
                      (index) => buildDot(index: index),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Spacer(
                    flex: 10,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: getPropotionateScreenWidth(300),
                      height: getPropotionateScreenHeight(56),
                      child: FloatingActionButton(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        ),
                        backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => SignInScreen(),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          "Continue",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: getPropotionateScreenWidth(18),
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  AnimatedContainer buildDot({required int index}) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: kAnimationDuration,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
      height: 6,
      width: currentPage == index ? 15 : 5,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: currentPage == index ? kPrimaryColor : Color(0xFFD8D8D8),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This error didn't exist the first time i ran the program.
Can anybody please help me with this porblem?

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
const Body(SafeArea Function(BuildContext context) param0, {super.key});
```

you declare that your constructor of a `Body` widget takes one required argument called `param0`. I don't see this argument being used anywhere in your code, so I assume it was added by mistake. You can fix the error message by replacing the above line with

```
const Body({super.key});
```

Then you can construct a new widget by calling `Body()` without any arguments required.

---

If however you do need that `param0` argument, you will have to specify it when creating a `Body` widget like this

```dart
return Scaffold(
  body: Body((BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Text("Some widget in here"); // Just an example
    )
  }),
);
```

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: What exactly "does not work"?